# Получить текущее состояние звука телефонного звонка

Tags: java, android

Существует сервис , в котором хотелось бы реализовать возможность определения текущего состояния звука телефона во время телефонного  звонка. Идет ли звук телефонного разговора на динамик или на блютус гарнитуру . Посмотрел в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html#getCallAudioState()) , что такой функционал дает `InCallService` в методе `getCallAudioState()`. Но не как не могу разобраться как это реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085978/android-how-to-check-phone-audio-output не то?

Comment: Почему то думал, что `AudioManager` подходит только для определения вывода звука музыки и подобного. 
Если я правильно понял в `AudioManager` нет прямого метода который определит что звук идет на разговорный динамик (не на громкую связь).  И для того что бы узнать идет ли на него звук надо просто проверить `isBluetoothScoOn()`, `isSpeakerphoneOn()`, `isWiredHeadsetOn()` (или функцию заменяющую `isWiredHeadsetOn()`)  и если все `false` то тогда звук идет на на динамик телефона для разговора, а не на громкую связь , так ?
Или все же есть более изящный способ ?